# Using select() in thread does not react os host disconnection

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select

I have main server code, which uses select and waits for hosts activities. 
I have also global structure, which stores all clients and theirs sockets.

//old code

Select in main thread unblocks intself when one of the hosts from clients array disconnects. Then I try to read data, and when it is 0, client is disconnected. Why select in Thread doesn't work in the same way? It works perfect when clients exchange data, but there is no reaction, when one of clients disconnects.

EDIT.

Sorry I have previously posted the code, which could not be compiled. The idea was, just to get the information if my idea of clients handling is correct and if this idea should work. I have created simple example and now it works. So, I have to review my oryginal code.

Working example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXCLIENTS 1000
#define FRAMESIZE 40

struct Client
{
  int socket;
  char state;
};
struct Client clients[2];

struct ThreadArgs
{
  int srcClientIdx;
  int dstClientIdx;
};

int portNumber=8090;

void * SocketThread(void *args)
{
   printf("New thread created.\n");
   struct ThreadArgs *threadArgs = (struct ThreadArgs*)args;
   int sidx = threadArgs->srcClientIdx;
   int didx = threadArgs->dstClientIdx;
   int srcSocket = clients[sidx].socket;
   int dstSocket = clients[didx].socket;

   fd_set readfds;
   struct timeval timeout;

   while(1)
   {
      FD_ZERO(&readfds);
      FD_SET(srcSocket, &readfds);
      FD_SET(dstSocket, &readfds);

      printf("Waiting for activities in thread.\n");

      timeout.tv_sec = 60;
      timeout.tv_usec = 0;
      int activity = select(MAXCLIENTS+1, &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);
      if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
         printf("Activity error.\n");
      else if(activity == 0)
         printf("Activity timeout.\n");

      if (FD_ISSET(srcSocket, &readfds))
      {
         unsigned char buffer[FRAMESIZE];
         int bytesCnt = read(srcSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
         if(bytesCnt == 0)
         {
           printf("Client%d disconnected.\n",sidx);
           clients[sidx].state = 0;
           clients[sidx].socket = -1;
           pthread_exit(NULL);
         }
         else
           printf("Client%d activity.\n",sidx);
      }

      if (FD_ISSET(dstSocket, &readfds))
      {
         unsigned char buffer[FRAMESIZE];
         int bytesCnt = read(dstSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
         if(bytesCnt == 0)
         {
           printf("Client%d disconnected.\n",didx);
           clients[didx].state = 0;
           close(clients[didx].socket);
           clients[didx].socket = -1;
           pthread_exit(NULL);
         }
         else
           printf("Client%d activity.\n",didx);
      }

   }
 }

 int ConfigureTCPIPconnection(int socket,struct sockaddr_in *serverAddr)
 {
   // Address family = Internet
   serverAddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
   //Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order
   serverAddr->sin_port = htons(portNumber);
   //Incoming addresses
   serverAddr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   //Set all bits of the padding field to 0
   memset(serverAddr->sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr->sin_zero);

   //Bind the address struct to the socket
   if(bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *)serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
   {
     printf("Binding failed. %s\n",strerror(errno));
     return 1;
   }

   printf("Bind sucessfull.\n");
   return 0;
 }

int CheckSocketActivity(fd_set *readfds)
{
   int activity = select( MAXCLIENTS + 1 , readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
   if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
      return 1;
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fd_set readfds;
  int serverSocket,newSocket;
  pthread_t td; //thread descriptor
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, newAddr={0};
  socklen_t addr_size;

  clients[0].state = 0;
  clients[0].socket = -1;
  clients[1].state = 0;
  clients[1].socket = -1;

  if((serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
  {
    printf("Server socket creation failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(ConfigureTCPIPconnection(serverSocket,&serverAddr))
  {
    printf("Binding failed.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  if(listen(serverSocket,MAXCLIENTS))
  {
    printf("Listen error.\n");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("Listening...\n");

  while(1)
  {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds); //clear fd set
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &readfds); //add server socket to fd set
    if(clients[0].state == 1)
      FD_SET(clients[0].socket, &readfds); //add active clients to fd set
    if(clients[1].state == 1)
      FD_SET(clients[1].socket, &readfds);

    printf("Waiting for activities.\n");

    if(!CheckSocketActivity(&readfds))
    {
      if(FD_ISSET(serverSocket, &readfds))
      {
        if((newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&newAddr, (socklen_t*)&addr_size))<0) //create new socket
          printf("New socket error. %s\n",strerror(errno));
        else
        {
          printf("New socket connected.\n");
          if(clients[0].state == 0)
          {
            printf("Client0 added.\n");
            clients[0].state = 1;
            clients[0].socket = newSocket;
          }
          else if(clients[1].state == 0)
          {
            printf("Client1 added.\n");
            clients[1].state = 1;
            clients[1].socket = newSocket;
          }
        }
      }
        else
        {
           for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
           {
              int srcSock = clients[i].socket;
              if (FD_ISSET(srcSock, &readfds))
              {
                 unsigned char buffer[FRAMESIZE];
                 int bytesCnt = read(srcSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                 if(bytesCnt == 0)
                 {
                   printf("Client%d disconnected.\n",i);
                   clients[i].state = 0;
                   close(clients[i].socket);
                   clients[i].socket = -1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   if(clients[0].state == 1 && clients[1].state == 1)
                   {
                      int srcIndex,dstIndex;
                      //some other stuff
                      clients[0].state = 2;
                      clients[1].state = 2;
                      if(i == 0)
                      {
                        srcIndex = 0;
                        dstIndex = 1;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        srcIndex = 1;
                        dstIndex = 0;
                      }
                      printf("Creating new thread.\n");
                      struct ThreadArgs threadArgs = {srcIndex,dstIndex};
                      if(pthread_create(&td, NULL, SocketThread, &threadArgs) != 0)
                         printf("Failed to create thread.\n");
                      if (pthread_detach(td))
                         printf("Thread detach error.\n");
                    }
                    else
                      printf("Two clients required for creating thread.\n");
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `select()` works the same in a child thread as it does in the main thread -- I use it that way all the time, and have done for many years.  So if it's not behaving as you expect, it's almost certainly due to some bug in the code, not because of `select()` itself.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you posted the code you are indeed dealing with because the code you posted shouldn't compile.

- Correction 1 (May not be the source of the problem)

From the `select()` man page:

```
void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

All `FD_*()` macros take `fd_set*` argument. In the `main()` you have passed `fd_set` instead of `fd_set*` at few places.

- Correction 2 (May be the source of the problem)

In `SocketThread()` this piece of code might be the cause of the issue:

```
  if (FD_ISSET(dstSocket, &readfds))
   {
      unsigned char buffer[FRAMESIZE];
      bytesCnt = read(srcSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
      if(bytesCnt == 0)
         **//this is not detected**
      else
        //any other activities are detected
   }
```

You may probably want `read(dstSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`.

Comment: I don't believe so, as he says it happens when a client disconnects.  IMHO the problem is the treatement he does when checking the return value of the select call.  He treats as valid (and process those completely in the code) on some errors (like the ones you post in your first case of using incorrect pointers)  Probably he is getting a lot of warnings about this, and don't show his compilation errors.  He started not showing his code, and telling that the failure was in the different behaviour of select() when used in threaded environments, as if the select called then was ...

Comment: ... different thant in non-threaded ones.

Answer (score -1):

(please, see below to see the full, complete answer to your question, again, once your code has been shown)

You say:

> Select in main thread unblocks intself when one of the hosts from clients array disconnects. Then I try to read data, and when it is 0, client is disconnected. Why select in Thread doesn't work in the same way? It works perfect when clients exchange data, but there is no reaction, when one of clients disconnects.

Please, you don't say how the client disconnects.  Does it just close the socket? does it do a shutdown? I don't see any `close(2)` on the socket, so why do you know who is closing the connection (or calling `shutdown(2)` to indicate that no more data is going to appear in the connection)?  Also, do you have one socket only per thread? do you share a socket between threads?  Are you reading actually the server socket in the client?  is this being done with the same thread?  do you have a `select()` per thread or there's a single thread reading the sockets and dispatching the messages to other threads to process?  I need to insist on providing a minimal and complete example of whay you are trying to ask, because it seems an instance of the XY problem.

> **Note:**  I have not explained why it is so important to know how the client disconnects from the server.  When you use TCP connections, the requests can be buffered, and so can the answers.  As it is too bad to wait for the previous response from the server to issue the next request (it empties the channel resulting in very bad performance) it is common to batch requests, and delimit answers from the server to distinguish then a protocol is actually finished.  What I'm trying to say is that if the client just `close(2)`s the connection, it is not just telling the kernel to send an end of file (a FIN segment) to the other side of the connection, but also it is signalling the kernel the unwillingness to receive more data on this connection, and this will make the TCP on the client side to reject (and send a RST or *as some Windows implementations do* set a window size of 0 which will never open again --resulting in a reset from the server, as no windows setting is allowed **after** a FIN segment has been sent)  I've seen both.  The problem is that the data that is still to be sent from the server to the client is lost (there's no way for the client to read it, if it has closed the connection, the socket descriptor is not available after a close, even if the close fails with error)  The reason of this note is that if the client code has just `close(2)`d the connection, he has done bad, and this can be the place where he is mistakenly assuming how things happen  (End of **Note**)

normally, a connection blocks until you receive some data... receiving 0 data means no data has arrived or, after a `select(2)` call has selected a socket descriptor that show no more data, then you have the socket closed.  But this has to be closed somewhere, and you show neither `close(2)` nor `shutdown(2)`.  You also don't describe what is what is detected on the socket.  If you awake from the `select(2)` you get to the file descriptor and the result from read is not `0` what value does the read return?  have you got acquainted that `-1` is one of such possible values, and that it means you have a readin error? Do you check the value returned by select?  (on timeout, my memory tells me that `select(0)` returns 0, so are you checking for timeout?)

---

After having a watch to your code you should first consider that the check for errors in select is incomplete:

```
      int activity = select(MAXCLIENTS+1, &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);
      if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
         printf("Activity error.\n");
      else if(activity == 0)
         printf("Activity timeout.\n");
```

should be (better :)):

```
      int activity = select(MAXCLIENTS+1, &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);
      if (activity < 0) {
         if (errno!=EINTR) {
             printf("Activity error.\n");
             continue; /* go back to the loop start, or break the
                        * loop, or exit or something
                        * as if you continue processing, you'll have
                        * no idea on what happen.  Probably both sockets
                        * will appeared as readable, untouched, as you
                        * have not succeeded in the select() call,  */
          } else {     /* error, and not a signal interruption, you
                        * should exit the loop, as signal doesn't
                        * work */
              printf("some select error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
              break;
          }
      } else if(activity == 0) {
         printf("Activity timeout.\n");
         /* in this case you are free to continue the loop down, but
          * there's no reason for that, you can do some housekeeping
          * and go up to the loop again */
         do_my_housekeeping();
         continue;
      }
```

I don't actually understand what is the reason for a single thread to have to read a pair of sockets, and this makes your example neither minimial nor complete (you don't do what is your thread doing with the data, just trashing it)

The only bad code I've seen (and it has costed me a downvote) is that you ignore the error from `select()` and continue processing, probably your non-threading code is different at this point, and that makes you thinking that when using threads, select behaves differently.  You should read about how threads are implemented  (there's a very good reference in McKusick's book *"The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System"*, and probably you should understand that the `select(2)` system call has no role in multithreaded programs.  No different system call is issued to the kernel when you run multithreaded applications, and this should have uncovered you the rabbit, to find that the error is in your code and not in `select(2)`.  I first assumed your code was correct, based on that you had not shown any code.  This costed me a downvote, because (IMHO) I was not focusing on the question.  But now your code is there, and it is incorrect, and I'd like to lose my downvote. :)

This error is very very frequent, so I will not downvote your question, more on, I'll upvote it, instead, but only after you have published a small (well, not minimalist, you had to see my sample code when I implement servers to my students, I don't use more than 100 lines of code)

**Second note:** you don't detect your EOF (well you detect it, but only once, as you continue selecting on the closed descriptor in the next loop when you FD_SET() it again.  This is an error, too, and you should not add it to the FD_SET() as soon as you have detected the EOF anymore (this is very important if you have several threads, because you will be feeding a closed descriptor that will make you fall now, but not if other thread creates a new socket and it results in the same value you have stored in the socket descriptor variable.
Different threads in a program share their file descriptors.

Comment: Receiving 0 means the peer has disconnected. Receiving -1 with `erroneous == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` means no data has arrived.

Comment: @user207421, that's only if you have used `O_NONBLOCK`  as an option, but that's not required with `select(2)` as you will not block (by requirement of `select()` call)  `Select()` will awake you if there's an EOF condition on input, so you will not block and is a good way to detect your connection has been blocked.

Comment: @user207421 The question poster does not say how the socket is disconnected.  It can be a half disconnect (by using the `shutdown()` socket call, which shows as reading 0 at the server side, by using the `close()` system call, which is equivalent to a full close, and will have the same effect on the server, or just `exit()` which forces the kernel to do the stuff)  In the case a close is actually made, the server could have been writting when this happened and when the data is received at the client, it can send a...

Comment: ... RST segment to indicate the uwillingness of the client to receive more data on that connection, and so the server will receive an error on the previous write, for being unable to write to the socket.  This situation is not ofen tested and results in application errors due to bad protocol implementation.  IMHO, in a REST protocol in which the client makes requests and the server responds, the client should always shutdown the writer side of the connection and close it completely when it receives the EOF from the server, and never before....

Comment: ...  Undetected loss of data is the most possible cause of not following this approach and a system error the less frequent (but most noticeable)